# Conservation of energy momentum tensor in curved space

Tags: general-relativity

A little confused about the right way to express the conservation of the stress tensor in curved space. In flat space time the conservation of the stress tensor is given by $\partial_{\mu}T^{\mu v} = 0$. I read that this expression in curved space is given by $\nabla_{\mu}T^{\mu v} = 0$. But, i don't know where i am wrong, shouldn't it be $\nabla_{\mu}T^{\mu v} - T^{\alpha v}\Gamma^{\mu}_{\alpha \beta} - T^{\mu \alpha} \Gamma^{v}_{\alpha \beta } = 0$?

Comment: Why would you think this? The general procedure to go from tensorial quantities on flat space to curved space, is by replacing partial derivatives with covariant derivatives.

Answer (score 2):

Flat-space equations go over to curved-space equations with the replacement of partial derivatives with covariant derivatives. That's the purpose of the covariant derivative, and they already include the necessary corrections. By sticking in the terms with Christoffel symbols, you're trying to make the same correction twice.

BTW, there's also something wrong with the indices in your expression. The $\mu$ indices don't match up in the three terms. Some have a free $\mu$ and some don't.

Answer (score 0):

In physics all objects have to be defined in a coordinate independent way. In particular, even in Minkowski spacetime, if you choose polar or spherical coordinates, the conservation law for the Stress-Energy tensor is not going to read

$$\partial_\mu T^{\mu\nu} = 0.$$

Instead, the correct coordinate independent of writing this law in a general coordinate system even in flat spacetimes is

$$\nabla_\mu T^{\mu\nu} = 0.$$

This will keep track of how the basis vector associated to this coordinate system change from point to point in spacetime and indeed, the Christoffel symbols in spherical/cylindrical/ any non parallel coordinates will be nontrivial. Thus, the generalization to general relativity is trivial: you simply take the same law as in Minkowski spacetime, but take under consideration the geometry of your spacetime instead.

Answer (score 0):

The conservation of the stress tensor is a physical property/law. As such it shouldn't depend on which coordinates you are using. The covariant derivative transforms like a tensor so it is coordinate independent. Remember that while vector *components* are transformed,
$$V^\mu\rightarrow\widetilde {V}^\mu=\frac{\tilde x^\mu}{x^\nu}V^\nu,$$
the combination of vector components and basis vectors is invariant:
$$\widetilde V=\widetilde V^\mu\tilde \partial_\mu=V^\mu\partial_\mu=V$$
So we can transform the law $\partial_\mu T^{\mu\nu}$, which holds in one particular frame, to a tensorial law which holds in any frame. We can do this by replacing the partial with a covariant derivative. Is this guaranteed to work? No! They are just not equal. But it makes sense that it very often does work. The covariant derivative reduces to the partial derivative in flat space. This means that if we see a law including the partial derivative in the lab frame a good guess would be that it came from a covariant derivative. In the case that it isn't true it would still be a good starting point.